# How can I filter and Parse object in Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6

I have JSON structure which I need to Map, Parse and Filter based on some attribute value to find out which object is containing that value so I can get other attributes of the same object and write my logic.

Below is the JSON Structure:

```
{
    "methods": [
        {
            "extension_attributes": {
                "time_slots": [
                    "{\"display_name\":\"Today\",\"date\":\"3\\\/3\\\/23\",\"internal_date\":\"2023-03-03\",\"disabled\":0}},\"timezone\":\"Asia\\\/Dubai\",\"shipping_identifier\":\"today\",\"selected\":1,\"disabled\":0}",
                    "{\"display_name\":\"Tomorrow\",\"date\":\"3\\\/3\\\/23\",\"internal_date\":\"2023-02-02\",\"disabled\":0}},\"timezone\":\"Asia\\\/Dubai\",\"shipping_identifier\":\"today\",\"disabled\":0}"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to map the JSON like below :

``

```
    filteredShippingMethods?.map(mapDeliveryDates)

    const mapDeliveryDates = (deliveryDate) => {
      return deliveryDate?.extensionAttributes?.timeSlots?.map((timeSlot) => {
      const deliveryDateParsed = JSON.parse(timeSlot)
      console.log ('deliveryDateParsed', deliveryDateParsed)
      // Above will return the data as in first image
      // I want to filter the data like below :
      const selectedShippingMethod = [deliveryDateParsed].filter((element) => element?.selected    === 1)
      console.log ('selectedShippingMethod', selectedShippingMethod)
     //Expecting to return only 1 object but it is returning like in second image
  })}
```

``

First output:
[image]

Final output:
[image]

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @MarioVernari When I filter, I only want 1 object, as you can see from my code and screenshot, it is returning both the objects, second one as empty.

Comment: For parsing filter and mapping to be more efficient you can use JavaScript lodash library.

Comment: That JSON does not match your code. Is it `extension_attributes` or `extensionAttributes`? Is it `time_slots` or `timeSlots`? The JSONs in `time_slots` are malformed -- they have more closing braces than opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you should not call `filter` **inside** the `map` callback, but **after** it -- chained according to this pattern: `.map().filter()`.

Like this:

```js
const filteredShippingMethods = [{
    extensionAttributes: {
        timeSlots: [
            "{\"display_name\":\"Today\",\"date\":\"3\\\/3\\\/23\",\"internal_date\":\"2023-03-03\",\"disabled\":0,\"timezone\":\"Asia\\\/Dubai\",\"shipping_identifier\":\"today\",\"selected\":1,\"disabled\":0}",
            "{\"display_name\":\"Tomorrow\",\"date\":\"3\\\/3\\\/23\",\"internal_date\":\"2023-02-02\",\"disabled\":0,\"timezone\":\"Asia\\\/Dubai\",\"shipping_identifier\":\"today\",\"disabled\":0}"
        ]
    }
}];

const mapDeliveryDates = (deliveryDate) =>
    deliveryDate?.extensionAttributes?.timeSlots
        ?.map(JSON.parse)
        ?.filter((element) => element?.selected === 1);

const result = filteredShippingMethods?.map(mapDeliveryDates);
console.log(result);
```